# Referring to unnumbered paragraphs

Tags: cross-referencing, paragraphs

I'd like to write

```
We added an explanation on \paragraphref{modifiedparagraph1}.
```

and have it compiled to:

```
We added an explanation on page 7, paragraph 2.
```

where the referenced paragraph is the second on the page not in the section.  Is there a package that can do this?

I'm aware of the possibility to refer to numbered paragraphs but that's not what I want because sections and paragraphs are not numbered in my document.

This feature would be very useful when writing response letters to journal editors.

Comment: For the page number it is quite easy using `\label{}` and `\pageref{}`. However for the paragraph number I do not have smart ideas for it just now. BTW I guess you made a typo in your question mixing explanation and sentence...

Comment: Techniques used for numbering footnotes per page may be useful here, but I foresee problems with paragraphs that are split between pages.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376865/9789) may be close to what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{parcount}[page]
\setcounter{parcount}{0}

\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}%
\stepcounter{parcount}%
\def\@currentlabel{\arabic{parcount}}}

\newcommand{\paragraphref}[1]{page \pageref{#1}, paragraph \ref{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Foo}
\label{Foo}
\lipsum[1]
See on \paragraphref{Bar}.


\paragraph{Bar}
\lipsum[2]
\label{Bar}

\newpage

\paragraph{Baz}

\paragraph{Foobar}
See on \paragraphref{Foo}.

\end{document}
```

And here are the output:

---

[image: Output 1]

---

[image: Output 2]

Comment: Add the lines `\lipsum[1-5]` at the top of your document.  The paragraph counting is off.   I'm not sure how you work around this.

Comment: @A.Ellett My solution is for counting the paragraphs defined by the `\paragraph` command. If the OP wants to count the paragraphs without using the `\paragraph` command then the solution needs to be changed to count the `\par` or something like that.

Comment: Counting `\par` will most likely not work since so many other LaTeX structures use `\par`.  But what I was trying to point out is that your `\paragraph` counting isn't quite working around page boundaries.  Try adding `\lipsum[1-5]` at the top of the document.  Even though those lines aren't `\paragraph`s in the manner of your style, the reference to your `\paragraph`s is still not correct.

Comment: Counting `\par`s is what I in fact intended to do.