# The number of a paragraph in a page

Tags: paragraphs, labels, ref

I need to mention that a concept is explained in paragraph x in page y.

Here, I have an example which shows paragraph number for me in a wrong way.
It shows paragraph 1 no matter which paragraph of the page the target is.

> Linux is explained in page 3, paragraph 1 at here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\mylink}[1]{{\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}page \pageref{#1}, paragraph \ref{#1}} at \hyperlink{#1}{here}}
\newcommand{\mytarget}[1]{\hypertarget{#1}{\label{#1}}}


\title{Your Paper}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Linux is explained in \mylink{linux}.

\lipsum[1-13]

\mytarget{linux}
This is a paragraph about Linux.

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This code in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/10121092jwnvtgnbhxcb#/37338338/

Comment: You are still in the first section… You need to add some sections/subsections to advance your counter. `ref` also does not count paragraphs in text blocks but refers to the surrounding section/subsection. You change the numbering scheme to count down to `\paragraph` (With a number code as `(chapter).section.subsection.paragraph.(subparagraph)`) but you still have to put in the block header (`\section{<name>}`)  yourself.

Comment: you need to add a command `\mypar` or `\startpar` at the start of each paragraph that step a counter `myparcounter`.

Comment: @Huang_d, I do not understand what you mean. Could you please edit the overleaf code?

Comment: @touhami, it is a good idea but a bit impractical.

Comment: IIRC, the paragraph counter is incremented by the \paragraph command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added a new counter (`parno`) which is incremented by `\everypar`.  Note that `\everypar` gets redefined and may need to be renewed frequently.

Also, `\label` refers to the last counter incremented by `\refstepcounter` and should therefore be closer to the start of the paragraph than any equation or other counter incrementing command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{parno}[page]
\renewcommand{\theparno}{page \thepage, paragraph \arabic{parno}}

\title{Your Paper}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\everypar{\refstepcounter{parno}}

Linux is explained in \ref{linux}.

\lipsum[1-13]

\leavevmode\label{linux}%
This is a paragraph about Linux. 

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there some way for the counter to include a partial paragraph at the start of a page? That is, if there is part of a paragraph that runs from the previous page to the current (i.e., the current page does not start with a fresh paragraph), the partial paragraph is counted as the first paragraph of the current page?

Comment: @FangJing - Try `\afterpage{\ifvoid\AP@partial \else \stepcounter\parno \fi}` (one page only).  Actually, you will need another macro for the test to loop it and \makatletter.